# LinqToSql Nullable Column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a table in my database which is named Patients. The table has a column which is named **DOB** and has Allow Null value to true. Here is the table structure:

- Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
- FirstName nvarchar(50) NULL,
- LastName nvarchar(50) NULL,
- Sex bit NULL,
- Weight decimal(18, 0) NULL,
- Height decimal(18, 0) NULL,
- **DOB date NULL**,
- PatientId nvarchar(50) NOT NULL

I'm using LinqToSql. The problem is that when I want to set a null for DOB column then Visual Studio tells that DOB is not nullable. Here is my code:

```
Patient tblPatient = new Patient();
if (txtYear.Text != "" && txtMonth.Text != "" && txtDay.Text != "")
                    tblPatient.DOB = Utility.ConvertPersianDateToGregorianDate(txtYear.Text + "/" + txtMonth.Text + "/" + txtDay.Text);
                else
                    tblPatient.DOB = null;  // The error is in this line
```

Comment: In your class `Patient` what is the type of `DOB` property?

Comment: @FelipeOriani, it is `DateTime`.

Comment: The David's awnser will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

What is the type for the `DOB` property on `Patient`?  Based on the description, presumably it's something like this (shortened for brevity):

```
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
```

In order to set a `null` value, it needs to be a nullable type, such as:

```
public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

When you generate the code from the data model, Linq to SQL should have done this for you.  If the code is manually created, you'll need to update it accordingly.  If it's auto-generated, you'll likely need to re-generate it.  (It seems likely that it was generated against an older model of the data where the column was not nullable.)

Comment: how do I re-generate the Patient table?

Comment: @Mohsen: How did you generate the Linq to SQL objects in the first place?  Re-run that.  If I remember correctly, there may be an option to update the code by right-clicking on the data context file in Visual Studio.  If not, you can always delete the generated Linq to SQL classes and re-generate them by adding a new one to the project.